# How remove time from date values pulled from a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, csv

I am working in python and using a JSON file and pulling info from it and sending to a csv file. The code I am using is as follows:

```
import csv
import json

csv_kwargs = {
    'dialect': 'excel',
    'doublequote': True,
    'quoting': csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
}

inpfile = open('checkin.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
outfile = open('checkin.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')

writer = csv.writer(outfile, **csv_kwargs, lineterminator="\n")

for line in inpfile:
    d = json.loads(line)
    writer.writerow([d['business_id'],d['date']])

inpfile.close()
outfile.close()
```

`checkin.json` key values of `business_id` and `date`.  The `date` values are in the form of `'MM:DD:YYYY HH:MM:SS'` where it shows the date and then the time.  Each `business_id` includes multiple dates associated with it.  I included a line of the JSON file to show how each `'business_id'` works and the dates associated with it.  A line from the JSON is shown below:

`{"business_id":"--1UhMGODdWsrMastO9DZw","date":"2016-04-26 19:49:16, 2016-08-30 18:36:57, 2016-10-15 02:45:18, 2016-11-18 01:54:50, 2017-04-20 18:39:06, 2017-05-03 17:58:02"}`

My question is how do you code this to keep the date, but not the time being that they are in the same key value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting for `date` values described in you question isn't consistent, first you say it's `MM:DD:YYYY`, however in the sample line from the json input file it appears to be `YYYY-MM-DD`, and while such details may matter, that particular one doesn't to the revised code below. What *did* matter was the fact that there can be more than one, which is why I'm updating my answer.

```
import csv
import json

csv_kwargs = {
    'dialect': 'excel',
    'doublequote': True,
    'quoting': csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
}

with open('checkin.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inpfile, \
     open('checkin.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as outfile:

    writer = csv.writer(outfile, **csv_kwargs)

    for line in inpfile:
        d = json.loads(line)
        # Convert date value string into list of dates with the times removed.
        dates = [date.strip().split(' ')[0] for date in d['date'].split(',')]
        writer.writerow([d['business_id']] + dates)
```

Comment: this worked however i should have mentioned that each business_id has multiple dates associated with it.  When i ran your code, it striped away the time but also any subsequent dates associated with that id

Comment: shamp7598: Yes, that would have been important to mention. If you edit your question and add a few sample lines from the json file, I can probably fix that (if you haven't figured it out yourself already).

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `date` in your JSON as a timestamp and then truncate it to date using Python's built-in `datetime` module.

Import the module:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Parse the `date` while writing:

```
for line in inpfile:
    d = json.loads(line)

    dates  = map(lambda dt: datetime.strptime(dt.strip(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), d['dates'].split(' '))
    for date in dates:
       writer.writerow([d['business_id'], date])
```

Comment: This didn't work, i received the error,         Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "checkin.py", line 20, in <module>
    d['date'] = datetime.strptime(d['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
  File "D:\obj\windows-release\37amd64_Release\msi_python\zip_amd64\_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
ValueError: unconverted data remains: , 2016-08-30 18:36:57, 2016-10-15 02:45:18, 2016-11-18 01:54:50, 2017-04-20 18:39:06, 2017-05-03 17:58:02

Comment: I didnt realize your date value is comprised of multiple dates. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're strictly using this program to convert the `json` file to csv, you can simply use string slices:

```
date, time = d['date'][:12], d['date'][12:]
```

If you want to store it as a `datetime` object to do something else

```
dt = time.strptime(d['date'], "'%m:%d:%Y''%H:%M:%S'")
# Other stuff
dt_string = dt.strftime("'%m:%d:%Y'")
```